# Extjs 3.4.1 Multiple calls to store to retrieve recount count

Tags: arrays, extjs, store

Please bear with me, I am very new to ExtJs. I have a requirement to display a count of all documents associated with a directory in a grid.  Using the column model I call the store with the grid rows directory information (passed as parameters to the store).  I then have a load listener in the store that has an array .push function for the record count.  This all works fine except when I display the array values in a test loop some, not all, of the values don't correspond to the known directory document count.

the values are correct overall but they are not in the correct element in the array and do not line up with the appropriate grid row. (i.e. array elements 0-10 correct, 11-13 scrambled, 14-30 correct, etc..). I did notice that the correct elements had no or very low record counts and the scrambled elements had relatively high record counts.

I believe that directories with large amounts of files are being pushed to the array after directories with smaller amounts files but I don't know how to test for or control this.

Any information / assistance with getting this information into the array correctly and possibly more efficiently (without making a boatload of calls to the store) would be greatly appreciated.

```
column model used with grid
.........
{header: col2, renderer: function(value, rowIndex, record){
   getCount(record.Name, record.Id);
}};
........

getCount = function(name, id){

store = data.store(){
baseParams: {name: name, id: id},
    listeners: {
       load: function(p, options){
            docCount.push(p.getCount());//global array
    }
       }
    };

  };
  store.load();
};
```

Comment: Your question is too vague, describing your code is a bad idea.

Comment: Not sure I understand your reply - simply, I make multiple calls to a store and push the record count to an array for future use. The count values in the array are correct but some are not in the correct order. calls that produce large record counts tend to be the ones that are not in the correct order whereas calls that produce 0 or small record counts are in the correct order with the exception of those effected by the corrupt elements.

Comment: Your code isn't working as you intended, you posted no code. How do you expect anyone to help?

Comment: I currently do not have access to the actual code but have provided gist from memory in original question.

Comment: the getCount is messed up, post the actual code please

Answer (score 0):

if you are getting your records Asynchronously, (i.e. using Ext.Ajax.request) your records come back as soon as your source is done creating them. Since they are async, the order they return will not be the same as they were requested since the source takes longer to return large calculations.

You could try to send a param with an index number(i.e. 'reqId', 'index',etc...) and have your source read it and return it with your result